# Is convergence in the norm equivalent to convergence of norms?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

If $\| \cdot \|$ is a norm on some space. Does the equivalence go both ways?

$$\| f_n-f \| \to 0 \Longleftrightarrow \| f_n\| \to \| f\| $$

The $\implies$ direction is obvious since $\| f_n-f \| \geq \Big| \| f_n\| - \| f\|\Big|$.

Yet I can neither prove nor disprove the other one. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: No, the first implies the 2nd, but not vice versa

Comment: $\left(-1\right)^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If you have a sequence of positive numbers that converges to a positive number, then if you multiply the sequence by $-1$ you get a negative sequence with the same norm that converges to a negative number. So can the reverse implication be true?

Answer (score 4):

Let $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{nx+1}$ and $f(x)=1$ and take the norm $$||f||_\infty=\sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)|$$
then we have
$$||f_n||_\infty=1=||f||_\infty$$
but 
$$||f_n-f||_\infty\ge f(1)-f_n(1)=\frac{n}{n+1}\not\to0$$